# EPSON FX-2175 dot matrix printer setup

Tags: 16.04, printing, epson, ubuntu-drivers

How can I add an **EPSON FX-2175** dot matrix printer to Ubuntu 16.04? It is installed but I can't get proper printer settings and drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the PPD file from here:

[Epson Dot Matrix](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Epson/Epson-Dot_Matrix)